# Rails ActiveRecord joins with selecting item with last id only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I have 2 models, Video and ZencoderJob. Each video `has_many` zencoder_jobs and zencoder_job `belongs_to` one video.

Now because a video can have multiple jobs (f.e. when you change the video file it will generate a new encoding job), there are many jobs with different encoding states. I use "processing" and "finished" to know when a video is ready to be shown through the API.

This is my actual query from video.rb

```
def self.finished_and_active(limit, offset)
  limit(limit || 30)
  .offset(offset.to_i || 0)
  .order("id DESC")
  .where(:active => true)
  .joins(:zencoder_jobs).where(:zencoder_jobs => { :encoded_state => "finished" })
  .uniq
end
```

The problem is that if there are 3 jobs for one video, 2 old and 1 new, the old jobs have a encoded_state of "finished" and the new has "processing". It does not look for the last ID of the job but if there is any job, no matter if old or new with "finished", it reveal it to the API.

I tried

```
.joins(:zencoder_jobs).where(:zencoder_jobs => { :encoded_state => "finished" }).last.uniq
```

but it throws an error because of "last". Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure what question you're asking. `last` is going to return only one object, not a collection, so calling `uniq` on that will throw an error, but I don't know what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: At the moment the video shows up even if the encoded_state of the latest job is "processing", because there are older jobs with the encoded_state "finished". I need it to look only at the last job, if its encodede_state is "finished" or not and ignore older jobs

Comment: What if the latest job is "finished" but jobs before that are still "processing"?

Comment: @Rachel Older jobs are ignored, or should be. I just care for the latest job's encoded_state

Answer (score 0):

Yuou can solve this problem by using some SQL magic. In the where part, insert `selecf max(zencoder_jobs.id) from zencoder_jobs where id = zencoder_jobs_id) = zencoder_jobs_id`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use addition options with join .Ex

```
Video.joins('LEFT JOIN zencoder_jobs ON  zencoder_jobs.video_id = video.id AND zencoder_jobs.encoded_state = "finished" ')
```

This will get you collection of videos and needed joined zencoder_jobs